# Given a tree represented in the form of nested lists, how do I traverse it breadth first?

Tags: algorithm, tree

Suppose I have the a tree given in the nested list representation, how do I traverse it breadth first? For example, if I'm given

```
[1, [2, [3, [4, [3, 5]]]], [3, [4, 5, 2]]]
```

The output would be 
`[1,2,3,3,4,4,5,2,3,5]`
Also, given a flattened representation of the depth-first order like `[1,2,3,4,3,5,3,4,5,2]`, how do I find the indices of the breadth-first order?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "the indices of the breadth-first order?"

Comment: So if a = [1,2,3,4,3,5,3,4,5,2], a[ 0,1,6,2,3,7,8,9,4,5] would give me [1,2,3,3,4,4,5,2,3,5]. [ 0,1,6,2,3,7,8,9,4,5] are the indices in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code in Python:

```
queue = [1, [2, [3, [4, [3, 5]]]], [3, [4, 5, 2]]]

while queue:
    firstItem = queue.pop(0)
    if type(firstItem) is list:
        for item in firstItem:
            queue.append(item)
    else:
        print('Traversed %d' % (firstItem))
```

The output is:

```
Traversed 1
Traversed 2
Traversed 3
Traversed 3
Traversed 4
Traversed 5
Traversed 2
Traversed 4
Traversed 3
Traversed 5
```

After studying my output and what you specified the output should be in your question, I think my output is more correct. More specifically, the left most `3` in the input list and `[4, 5, 2]` at the end of the input list are on the same "level", and thus should be traversed `3, 4, 5, 2`, as shown from the 4th line to the 7th line of my output.

---

As for your second question, I think you should ask a separate question because it really is a completely different question.

Comment: You're right about the output. My bad. But when I tried it on this input:
[1, [2, [3, 4, [3, 5]], 3, [4, 5, 2]]] it gives me the following output:
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5]. Shouldn't it be:
[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5] ?

Comment: @Aditya369 Yes, it should be `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 2, 3, 5]`, and that is what I get when I run it...